# React: To know size of the element before it gets rendered

Tags: reactjs

Suppose that a component needs to know its size before it renders. With my knowledge I can do this:
render the component, in componentDidMount get the DOM node and extract size out of it, update state with that size, and then render again (lets not make it complicated with event listeners I'd attach to window's resize event, lets assume that window doesn't resize)
It works but seems dirty, the first render is just waste of resources, I wanna know the size of the element (or its container) before it's rendered, I know most of the time the element itself declares the size, but there are some situations when parent element declares the size and my case is one of those situations.
So to sum it up, is there any way to access parent element of a react component before it gets rendered (in componentWillMount)?

P.S. I know react-dimmensions, but I'd like a simpler solution that doesn't need external plugins. I just wanna know if it's possible to access parent node in componentWillMount in react or not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is no, but please read for ideas how to cope.

If the DOM element doesn't exist, you can't find its dimensions.  The DOM element doesn't exist until the first render for each component has been done.  You can't know anything about this DOM element or its parent until the component's `componentDidMount()` is called.

Note also the order that components are rendered.  On the initial rendering of a tree/chain of components, the child's `componentDidMount()` will be called before the parent's `componentDidMount()` !  Here's a snapshot of logs from a nested menu tree:

```
(MenuItemSubmenu:handleRefSet)          appMenu:2.2.5.4   handleRefSet()
(MenuItemSubmenu:componentDidMount)     appMenu:2.2.5.4   componentDidMount()
(MenuPane:handleRefSet)                 appMenu:2.2.5   handleRefSet()
(MenuPane:componentDidMount)            appMenu:2.2.5   componentDidMount()
(MenuItemSubmenu:handleRefSet)          appMenu:2.2.5   handleRefSet()
(MenuItemSubmenu:componentDidMount)     appMenu:2.2.5   componentDidMount()
(MenuPane:handleRefSet)                 appMenu:2.2   handleRefSet()
(MenuPane:componentDidMount)            appMenu:2.2   componentDidMount()
(MenuItemSubmenu:handleRefSet)          appMenu:2.2   handleRefSet()
(MenuItemSubmenu:componentDidMount)     appMenu:2.2   componentDidMount()
```

`componentDidMount()` for child item 2.2.5.4 is called before that for its parent item 2.2.5.  From that we can see that the parent component can't know its own DOM element until all processing for the child has completed.  Um, wow!

However, pursuing your question, I added some logging to a component's `componentDidMount()` method.  I logged `this.refToOurDom.parentElement` and found that it was defined and looked good!

```
(MenuItemSubmenu:handleRefSet)  appMenu:2.2.5.4   parent dims:  height 76   width 127
```

So the answer to your question is, no, your DOM element doesn't exist yet in `componentWillMount()` and the parent doesn't exist either on initial render.  You must wait until `componentDidMount()` is called before finding out any component's dimensions.

But please note the trick that [`react-dimensions`](https://github.com/digidem/react-dimensions/blob/master/index.jsx#L160) uses.  Perhaps that will give you ideas how to structure your code.

In its `render()` method `react-dimensions` **may not render** the enclosed component!  On the initial render it only renders the containing <div>.  Only after its `componentDidMount()` is called and it finds out the parent's dimensions, **only then** will the enclosed component be rendered, **and now** supplying the parent's dimensions.

So another answer is just don't render your component's contents until you know the dimensions of the parent.  Using `react-dimensions` makes that easy, because you aren't even rendered until the dimensions are known.  But you could also do the same sort of thing, getting the reference in your `componentDidMount()` and grabbing dimensions, and simply putting an `if(){}` around rendering the *real* contents of your component until you know the dimensions. (You'll need at least an outer <div> to get your own ref)

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I got by reading react-dimensions code too. I thought maybe root element's parent element (which isn't rendered in react) is available before componentWillMount and as you clearly answered it's not available. Thanks for details.